# @InvocableMethod and @InvocableVariable in Salesforce

Tags: apex, rest, flow, apexrest, invocable-method

I am trying to learn about these two annotations that has been introduced as Spring 15 release. Can anyone please explain why and under what circumstances do we need to use these two annotations. An example would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question [Can't invoke @InvocableMethod via the REST API](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/64116/102) gives a working example of calling the resulting REST service with workbench.

Comment: I saw this Daniel. Thank you. I just wanted to understand this in simple words and then dig deeper into various blogs. Do you think you can help me with that?

Comment: [InvocableVariable](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableVariable.htm) allows you to "a class variable used as an input or output parameter for an [InvocableMethod](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm) method’s invocable action".

Comment: @sfdcfox - Could you please explain the solution to this question based on your person experience and findings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [the Spring 15 release notes](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring15/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_apex.htm). [@InvocableMethod](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm) exists to make it easier for a flow to call a method on an Apex class. It has some limitations around the supported data types that can be passed to the method, but should be simpler than implementing the [Process.Plugin Interface](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_process_plugin.htm)

Have a look at the example in the release notes that demonstrates getting the account ids by name. The @InvocableMethod is much shorter (11 lines to 28) and more straight forward to follow. As noted, the shorter version is also more efficient when dealing with multiple records.